# Application.get_env/2 is returning nil for definitions made in config.exs

Tags: elixir

I have an umbrella app that defines some env variables using the `prod.exs`, `dev.exs` and `config.exs` files.

Everything defined in `prod.exs` and `dev.exs` can be read using `Application.get_env/2`, but when I define the variables inside the `config.exs` the function returns `nil`.

Here is how my `config.exs` file looks like:

```
import Config

config :my_umbrella_app, MyModule.Scheduler,
  timezone: "Etc/UTC",
  jobs: [
    get_data: [
      schedule: "00 00 * * *",
      task: {MyModule, :execute, []}
    ]
  ]

import_config "#{Mix.env()}.exs"
```

When running: `Application.get_env(:my_umbrella_app, MyModule.Scheduler)` the response is `nil`

However, if I move this Scheduler configuration to `dev.exs` and run the same command again, I get the defined object.

What is wrong with this `config.exs` file definition?

Comment: Could it be getting overrid in `dev.exs`?

Comment: I remember having a similar issue - `mix clean`  and `mix compile --force` helped - did you already try it? :)